# Elasticsearch [bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some problem with the elasticsearch query.
when I use the query code it feedback the messages
`[bool]` malformed query, expected `[END_OBJECT]` but found `[FIELD_NAME]`.

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
     "must": {
      "match": {
       "_index": "ntopng-2017.07.26" 
      }
    },
      "filter": {
       "term": {
        "IPV4_DST_ADDR": "192.168.0.1"
    }
  }

} ,
"aggs" : {
    "IN_PKTS" : { "sum" : { "field" :"IN_PKTS" } },
    "IN_BYTES" : {"sum" : { "field":"IN_BYTES"} } ,
    "OUT_BYTES" : {"sum" : { "field":"OUT_BYTES"} }, 
    "OUT_PKTS" : { "sum" : { "field" :"OUT_PKTS" } }

   } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*aggs* is misplaced. Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "_index": "ntopng-2017.07.26"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "IPV4_DST_ADDR": "192.168.0.1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "aggs": {
      "IN_PKTS": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "IN_PKTS"
        }
      },
      "IN_BYTES": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "IN_BYTES"
        }
      },
      "OUT_BYTES": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "OUT_BYTES"
        }
      },
      "OUT_PKTS": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "OUT_PKTS"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: @張皓翔 You're welcome :) if it does, please accept the answer.

Comment: Dear aclokay, may I ask you a question that the total hit is
634,but the browser display only a few data is it correct?

Comment: Yes, as most search engine, they give you only the most relevant _X_ results. You can specify the total hits you want and the offset in the result set:
See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html

Comment: great! I got it.

Comment: @張皓翔 Awesome! Please accept the answer! https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer